# Question on unipotent radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a linear algebraic group then its unipotent radical $R_u(G)$ is normal in $G$.

> Is it also contained (and normal) in $G^0$?

Comment: Any normal subgroup is normal in any subgroup that contains it. BTW, the second time you wrote "unipotent" you surely meant "radical", didn't you?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is contained there? It is clearly normalized by it.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, I've edited the question. I wrote the question a bit too much in a hurry, so my question was actually also about the containment.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The question was about both containment and normality, but I've realized the triviality of the normality. $R_u(G)$ should be contained in $G^0$ right?

Comment: How have you had the unipotent radical defined?